# Change version of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently downloaded the latest version of android Studio and this is giving me a lot of problems. Some of my old projects don't work due to compatibility issues, so I wanted to know if it was possible to revert to an older version of Android Studio and how I can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You can uninstall the current Android Studio and then, you can search [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) for the version you would like to download.